# Bootstrap modal background changes its transparency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have simple login form that is inside Bootstrap modal.

Sometimes, launching this modal gives me completely black background, but in settings I have opacity 0.5 or something.

When I refresh page and relaunch modal it works just fine again.

My modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="required_authentication" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog log-modal">
    <div class="modal-content log-input">                                                                               
      <div class="ajax-partal-field">

        <%= render partial: "reusable/login" %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have searched for similar issues, but didn't find anything.
Thanks!

Comment: Need a bit more to go on, sorry! Do you have any more code, or something I can poke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the modal to a different position in the DOM, and make sure you HTML validates for the entire page.